# What is the difference between upper case and lower case built-in variables in Linux like HOME and eval

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, eval

What are the differences between upper case and the lower case built in variables in Linux like `HOME` and `eval`?

Comment: `eval` is not a variable, but a builtin command. Variables and shell builtins are completely different things.

Comment: See `help eval` or man page style: `help -m eval | less`

Answer (score 2):

`HOME` is an environment variable. If you are using bash, `eval` is a [builtin](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/eval), not a variable at all.

Comment: `eval` is a bash builtin command.

Comment: Thank you for the correction, @Cyrus. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

All uppercase names are used for environmental variables which would be shared by all commands and programs invoked through the shell or a startup script.  All lowercase with underscores (sometimes called snake case) is used for variables used within a program.

Shell built-in variables like HOME, PS1, PS2, TERM, LOGNAME, USER etc., are all in upper case.

See this page for more info:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42847/are-there-naming-conventions-for-variables-in-shell-scripts